# Index not used in a partitioned Oracle table

Tags: index, oracle-11g-r2, partitioning

I have a table partitioned by list

```
create table ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT
(
  code_exercice           VARCHAR2(4),
  CODE_PRODUIT            VARCHAR2(2),
  .......
)
partition by list (CODE_EXERCICE)
(
  partition CODE_EXERCICE_2018 values ('2018')
    tablespace DATA_BI_PARTITION_2018
  ,
  partition CODE_EXERCICE_2019 values ('2019')
    tablespace DATA_BI_PARTITION_2019
    ,
  partition CODE_EXERCICE_2020 values ('2020')
    tablespace DATA_BI_PARTITION_2020
   ,
  partition CODE_EXERCICE_2021 values ('2021')
    tablespace DATA_BI_PARTITION_2021
    
);
```

and i have 2 indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX EKIPIC.IDX_CODE_EXERCICE ON EKIPIC.ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT
(CODE_EXERCICE)
  TABLESPACE INDEX_BI
  
LOGGING
LOCAL (  
  PARTITION CODE_EXERCICE_2018
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE INDEX_BI_PARTITION_2018,  
  PARTITION CODE_EXERCICE_2019
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE INDEX_BI_PARTITION_2019,  
  PARTITION CODE_EXERCICE_2020
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE INDEX_BI_PARTITION_2020,  
  PARTITION CODE_EXERCICE_2021
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE INDEX_BI_PARTITION_2021
)

ONLINE;

create index IDX_CODE_PRODUIT on ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT (CODE_PRODUIT)
  tablespace INDEX_BI
 ;
```

the explain plan show a full scan access when i perform

```
 SELECT * from ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT
where code_produit='LOA'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name             | Rows   | Bytes     | Cost  | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                  | 812259 | 242053182 | 32268 | 00:07:32 |
|   1 |   PARTITION LIST ALL |                  | 812259 | 242053182 | 32268 | 00:07:32 |
| * 2 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT | 812259 | 242053182 | 32268 | 00:07:32 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - filter("CODE_PRODUIT"='LOA')
```

the same way when i try to use

```
select * from ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT i where i.code_exercice='2019'

 Plan Hash Value  : 2304474508 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation               | Name             | Rows    | Bytes     | Cost  | Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                  | 1604226 | 474850896 | 12511 | 00:02:56 |
|  1 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE |                  | 1604226 | 474850896 | 12511 | 00:02:56 |
|  2 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | ICT_ENCOURS_BRUT | 1604226 | 474850896 | 12511 | 00:02:56 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why cannot use the indexes  assuming that stats is updated?

Comment: How many unique `code_produit` are there, and how many rows in the table overall?

Comment: It is not a problem if the full scan is faster than the index scan. Try running your queries with an index hint and see if they are faster than the unhinted plan.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a waste of time using an index when you ask for all rows of a partition.

Also, searching for 'LOA' in a varchar2(2) column has little chance of success.

Comment: An index that covers a column which is filtered with a known false condition would be a good idea. The likelihood is, in this table there is a small number of distinct values of this column and the min/max range covers the literal value in the query. It seems that the optimizer doesn’t pay attention to the length of the value and column when deciding cardinality (as it is very unusual to search for impossible values).